Connected part of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\overline{\mathbb F}_p)$
I'm trying to understand a condition in the main theorem of Fakhrudin–Khare–Patrikis' paper Relative deformation theory, relative Selmer groups, and lifting irreducible Galois representations in Duke.
Let $G$ be a smooth group scheme over $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}_p$, $F$ is any number field and let $\overline{\rho}: \Gamma_{F,S} \rightarrow G(k)$ (where $\Gamma_{F,S}$ is the Galois group of the maximal extension of $F$ unramified outside $S$ and $k$ is the residue field of $O$).
In theorem A and B they say $\tilde{F}$ is the smallest extension of $F$ such that $\overline{\rho}(\Gamma_{\tilde{F},S}) \subset G^0 (k)$.
If $G=\operatorname{GL}_2 (\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)$ where $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the finite field of $p$ elements what is this extension $\tilde{F}$? What's an example of $\tilde{F}$ if $F$ is totally real or a general number field?

(1) Doesn't this depend on what $\overline\rho$ is, and (2) I'm not quite sure how to understand $\operatorname{GL}_2(\overline{\mathbb F}_p)$ as a smooth group scheme over $\overline{\mathbb Z}_p$, but shouldn't it already be connected?

There are other conditions on $\overline{\rho}$ (odd, absolutely irreducible) but If $GL_2(\overline{F}_p)$ is connected then $\tilde{F} = F$, right?

If $G$ is connected, for example $G = \mathrm{GL}2$, then $G = G^0$ and so $\tilde{F} = F$. In general, as @LSpice said, $\tilde{F}$ will depend on $\overline{\rho}$. It is simply the Galois extension of $F$ corresponding to the kernel of the map $\Gamma{F,S} \to G(k)/G^0(k)$ induced by $\overline{\rho}$.
